# kotlin coroutines trying to build recipes app based on recipessdb with kotlin +coroutines and mvvm but i have an error that i don't know

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

`here is my api sevice`

```
 interface GetDataServices {
        @GET("categories.php")
        suspend fun getCategoryList(): Category
```

`here is my Repositor`

```
class Repository(
    var getDataService : GetDataServices ?=null,
    var dao: RecipeDao?=null,
    var application: Application
){

    //-1-get Main category from api
     suspend fun getMainCategory(): Category? {
         var res_rep= getDataService?.getCategoryList()
        return res_rep
        Log.v("res_rep_get",res_rep.toString())
     }
}
```

`here is my ViewModel`

```
class CategoryViewModel: ViewModel(){
    var repository:Repository?=null

    var  mainCategoryList:MutableLiveData<ArrayList<CategoryItems>?>?=MutableLiveData()

 
suspend fun getMainCategory(){
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    repository= Repository()

    val result= withContext(Dispatchers.IO){

        repository?.getMainCategory()

    }


    mainCategoryList!!.value = result!!.categoriesitems as ArrayList<CategoryItems>?


}
}

}
```

`here is my activity`

```
@OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
class SplashActivity : BaseActivity(), EasyPermissions.RationaleCallbacks,
    EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks {

    private var READ_STORAGE_PERM = 123
    lateinit var categoryViewModel: CategoryViewModel
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)

        GlobalScope.launch {
          //  readStorageTask()
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                getCategories()
            }

        }
        
    }


    suspend fun getCategories() {
        categoryViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(CategoryViewModel::class.java)

        categoryViewModel!!.getMainCategory()

        categoryViewModel.mainCategoryList?.observe(this) { value ->
            value?.let {
                Log.d("cor_get", value.toString())
            }
        }

    }
```

`here isُError`

> ```
>   com.example.foodrecipeapp.viewmodel.CategoryViewModel$getMainCategory$2.invokeSuspend(CategoryViewModel.kt:26)
>             at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
>             at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
> ```

`here isُ another Error`

```
    at com.example.foodrecipeapp.viewmodel.CategoryViewModel$getMainCategory$2.invokeSuspend(CategoryViewModel.kt:26)
```

`here is my dependincies`

> def lifecycle_version = "2.5.0-alpha01"
> def arch_version = "2.1.0"
> implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
> // ViewModel utilities for Compose
> implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:$lifecycle_version")
> // LiveData
> implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
>
> ```
> kapt("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.5.0")
> ```

Comment: There can be another error description in the stack trace, it would be helpful if you posted it all.

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
    Process: com.example.foodrecipeapp, PID: 8727
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.foodrecipeapp.viewmodel.CategoryViewModel$getMainCategory$2.invokeSuspend(CategoryViewModel.kt:31)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)

Answer (score 0):

1. You're doing your api request from the main thread

   val result = withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { repository?.getMainCategory() }

Just leave it as

```
val result = repository?.getMainCategory()
```

I would guess that you're receiving an error from Retrofit about sending requests from the main thread.

2. You have too many wrappers withContext(), you don't need them.
3. You shouldn't use GlobalScope.launch for such cases as in your SplashActivity. Just operate viewModelScope and that would be enough.
4. Add a brief error handling. `result!!.categoriesitems` will always fail if your server returns any http error or there is no internet connection

Please also take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines). It has a great explanation about using scopes and creating coroutines.

Comment: it's my first kotlin and coroutines bro but I tried what u hint but still makes error

Comment: still this is my error atcom.example.foodrecipeapp.viewmodel.CategoryViewModel$getMainCategory$2.invokeSuspend(CategoryViewModel.kt:32)

Comment: @Abdulrahman then please put your >Log.v("res_rep_get",res_rep.toString()) before the >return res_rep and paste the log here

Comment: V/res_rep_get: null

Comment: @Abdulrahman So it means that your response is null. When you're creating your repository = Repository(), you're not passing an instance of GetDataService and it's null by default. You need to instantiate it properly, please read how to create a Retrofit service

Answer (score 0):

`var repository` is declared but not instantiated.

```
class CategoryViewModel: ViewModel(){
        /*
         *Declared but not instantiated
         */
        var repository:Repository?=null
    
        var  mainCategoryList:MutableLiveData<ArrayList<CategoryItems>?>?=MutableLiveData()
    
        suspend fun getMainCategory(){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val result= withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
    
                repository?.getMainCategory()
    
            }
            mainCategoryList!!.value = result!!.categoriesitems as ArrayList<CategoryItems>?
    
    
        }
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: i instantiate it but it still makes errors

Comment: show your update in the question.

Comment: updated bro......

Comment: i guess tha t livedata dependecy is the cause? can be ??

Comment: `Repository()` - this can't be.  This class takes parameters, you are providing none.